# If $f_n:X\to\mathbb{R}$ converge uniformly a $f$, then there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N\to f_n(X)\subseteq U$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $X$ be a compact, $U$ open set and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous such that $f(X)\subseteq U$.

If $f_n:X\to\mathbb{R}$ converge uniformly a $f$, then there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ implies $f_n(X)\subseteq U$.

A suggestion please.

Comment: What does $N\rightarrow f_n(X)$ mean?

Comment: @ACV: It's a logical implication. The arrow means "then".

Comment: What have you try up to now ? I think you can do it pointwise (easy) then on small open balls around each elements and then using compacity of $X$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous, we know that $f(X)$ is compact and since it sits inside $U$ we know it has positive distance from $\mathbb{R} \setminus U$. Write $d(f(X), \mathbb{R} \setminus U) = \delta$. Then, if you choose $N$ such that for all $n > N$ you have $||f_n - f||_{\infty} < \frac{\delta}{2}$ then for **any** $y \notin U$ we have

$$ |f_n(x) - y| = |f_n(x) - f(x) + f(x) - y| \geq ||f_n(x) - f(x)| - |f(x) - y|| \geq \frac{\delta}{2} $$

and in particular, $f_n(x) \notin \mathbb{R} \setminus U$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any $x \in X$. Consider $f(x) \in U$. Since $U$ is open, and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$, for large enough n, $f_n(x) \in U$. Even more, since $f_n \to f$ uniformly, there's an open neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that for large enough $n$, $f_n(U_x) \subset U$.

Now use compactness to patch all "large enough n" for all $U_x$ to get a single "large enough n" to work with all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the statement is not true. Then, for every $N$, there exist $n_N \ge N$ with $f_{n_N} (X) \nsubseteq U$. This means that there exist $x_N \in X$ such that $f_{n_N} (x_N) \notin U$. Since $X$ is compact, $(x_N)$ must have a convergent subsequence. By passing to this subsequence, we may assume (for convenience) that $(x_N)$ itself is convergent, to some $x \in X$.

Since $U$ is open, for sufficiently small $r>0$ we may find an open interval $\big( f(x)-r, f(x)+r \big)$ contained in $U$. Since $f_{n_N} (x_N) \notin U$, it obviously follows that $f_{n_N} (x_N) \notin \big( f(x)-r, f(x)+r \big)$, which means that $|f_{n_N} (x_N) - f(x)| \ge r$.

Finally,

$$r \le |f_{n_N} (x_N) - f(x)| = |f_{n_N}(x) - f(x_N) + f(x_N) - f(x)| \le |f_{n_N}(x) - f(x_N)| + |f(x_N) - f(x)| \le \\
\|f_{n_N} - f\| + |f(x_N) - f(x)| \underset {N \to \infty}\longrightarrow 0 ,$$

which is a contradiction.

($\|g\|$ is defined as $\sup \limits _{x \in X} |g(x)|$ and $\|f_n - f\| \to 0$ is equivalent to saying that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$.)